# Bulk insert in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bulkinsert, table-relationships

I cannot solve the following problem
Any help or suggestion is appreciated

Agent collects orders for Product on a paper going from one Shop to another in his Region.

At the end of the day, he inserts the quantity of each Product to each Shop.

Each Shop orders more than 4 types of products.

I need to design to be able to bulk insert.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Shop1</td>
    <td>Product1</td>
    <td>Product2</td>
    <td>Product3</td>
    <td>Product4</td>
    etc...
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Shop2</td>
    <td>Product1</td>
    <td>Product2</td>
    <td>Product3</td>
    <td>Product4</td>
    etc...
  </tr>
  etc...
</table>
```

In the browser it needs to look as below
[image]

Comment: you can use CSV or Excel import functionality

Comment: At the moment we are doing all this calculation on Excel already, as I wrote above an agent collects orders on paper, then we insert orders to Excel one by one. Instead we want to insert data directly to application the same way, but all the calculation will be done by application itself. If we put Excel import functionality, we need to insert to Excel then to application, it is like double work... Yes, it is a good idea if orders are collected by hand terminal which saves all on excel or csv file, which can be imported directly to application later. But now we cannot afford hand terminals

Comment: Anyway, thank you for the response!

Comment: You might want to look at the idea of a service and form object instead of trying to shoehorn the functionality in to a model.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to use a custom form model. [This](https://coderwall.com/p/kvsbfa/nested-forms-with-activemodel-model-objects) is a pretty good guide on the subject. This may not be perfect, but should get you on the right track at least. All credit to the following (slightly modified for your question) code goes to [Sam Slotsky](https://coderwall.com/sslotsky) from the blog linked above. Read the post for more detail about each piece.

Here's the custom form model:

```
class ProductForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :products

  def products_attributes=(attributes)
    @products ||= []
    attributes.each do |i, product_params|
      @products.push(Product.new(product_params))
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @product_Form = ProductForm.new(products: [Product.new])
  end

  def create
    @product_form = ProductForm.new(params[:product_form])

    if @product_form.save
      flash[:notice] = "Created products"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:notice] = "There were errors"
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the view:

```
<div>
  <%= form_for @product_form, url: products_path, method: :post do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :products do |c| %>
      <%= c.text_field :attr_1 %>
      <%= c.text_field :attr_2
      <%- # ... etc ... %>
    <% end %>

    <p>
      <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```